# How does an augmentation of a cosimplicial space give an augmentation of its realization tower?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff, spectral-sequences

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a cosimplicial space and let the realization tower be a collection of simplicial sets $Tot_s{C}$ fitting into a tower $ ... \to Tot_s{C} \to Tot_{s-1}{C}...$.  I will now define the simplicial set $Tot_s{C}$:

Let $\Delta_{(s)}$ be the s-skeleton of the cosimplicial space $\Delta$.  Thus $\Delta_{(s)}$ is the minimal cosimplicial space whose $i$'th simplicial sets $i \leq s$ are the simplicial sets $\Delta_i$.

Define $Tot_s{C}$ to be the function complex $Hom_{\text{Cosimplicial spaces}}(\Delta_{(s)}, \mathbf{C})$.

---

Why does an augmentation of $\mathbf{C}$,

*i.e. a map of simplicial sets $X \xrightarrow{\eta} \mathbf{C}([0])$ such that the maps  $d^1_0, d^0_0:C([0]) \to C([1])$ satisfy $d^1_0 \circ  \eta=d^0_0 \circ \eta$,*

even give a map from $X \to Tot_s{C}$, say for $s=0$?

My motivation for asking is that this is part of an an assertion on page 3 of [a paper on the Eilenberg Moore spectral sequence](https://www3.nd.edu/~wgd/Dvi/StrongConvergenceEilenbergMoore.pdf).  (The assertion that the paper gives is that there is an augmentation of the tower $Tot_s{C}$.)

For the record, $\Delta$ denotes the cosimplicial space that when applied to $[n]$ gives the simplicial set $\Delta_n=Hom( \cdot, [n])$.

Comment: I think the question is well posed now :).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something along the following lines.

First, $\operatorname{Tot}_0(\mathbf{C})$ is just $\mathbf{C}[0]$, and we can take the map $X \to \operatorname{Tot}_0(\mathbf{C})$ to be the given augmentation $X \to \mathbf{C}[0]$.

In general, an augmentation $\eta: X \to \mathbf{C}[0]$ extends uniquely by the cosimplicial identities to a map of cosimplicial spaces $\tilde{\eta}: cX \to \mathbf{C}$ where $cX$ is the constant (aka discrete) cosimplicial space.  By postcomposition this gives a map $$X \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{cS}(\Delta_{(s)}, cX) \xrightarrow{\tilde{\eta}_*} \operatorname{Hom}_{cS}(\Delta_{(s)}, \mathbf{C}) = \operatorname{Tot}_s(\mathbf{C}).$$

By naturality, this is compatible with the cofibration $\Delta_{(s)} \to \Delta_{(s+1)}$, so this gives a compatible system of maps $\{X \to \operatorname{Tot}_s(\mathbf{C})\}$.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{Tot}_s(\mathbf{C})$ just a disjoint union of simplicial sets

 $Hom_{\text{simplicial sets}}(\Delta[0], C[0]) \sqcup \cdots\sqcup Hom_{\text{simplicial sets}}(\Delta[s], C[s])$? 


 If this is the case then wouldn't the map $X \to \operatorname{ Tot}_s(\mathbf{C})$ just be the composition $X \to C[0] \hookrightarrow \mathbf{C[0]} \sqcup Hom_{\text{simplicial sets}}(\Delta[1], C[1]) ...\sqcup Hom_{\text{simplicial sets}}(\Delta[s], C[s])$?

Comment: I don't think your description of $\operatorname{Tot}_s(\mathbf{C})$ is quite correct.  $\operatorname{Tot}_{s}(\mathbf{C})$ should be the fiber product of $\operatorname{Tot}_{s-1}(\mathbf{C})$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(\Delta[n], \mathbf{C}[n])$ over $\operatorname{Hom}(\partial \Delta [n], \mathbf{C}[n]) \times_{\operatorname{Hom}(\partial \Delta [n], M^{n-1} \mathbf{C})} \operatorname{Hom}(\Delta[n], M^{n-1} \mathbf{C})$.   See chapter VIII of Goerss-Jardine.